# Dojo Ellipsis Function Deferred Error?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, dojo, deferred

I have a problem with a piece of code in JavaScript + dojo. I'm making a widget that given a certain height and a string, the widget displays that string with an ellipsis at the end if the string overflows. There's two ways of using this widget, you can either feed it the actual string or give it a URL to a text file.

The problem is that if you feed the actual string to the widget, it fails but if you give it the URL it works perfectly. Here's the code:

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare","dijit/_WidgetBase", "dijit/_TemplatedMixin", "dojo/text!./template/template.html", "dojo/_base/xhr", "dojo/dom-style", "dojo/_base/lang"],

function(declare, WidgetBase, TemplatedMixin, template, xhr, domStyle, lang){

 return declare([WidgetBase, TemplatedMixin], {

        templateString: template,

        textSrc: "",

        content: "",

        height: 100,

        ellipsis: "...",

        endPoint: "Read more...",

        postCreate: function(){
            this.inherited(arguments);

        },

        _setHeightAttr: function(av) {
            this._set("height", av);
            domStyle.set(this.domNode, "height", this.height +"px");
        },

        _setContentAttr: function(av) {
            this._set("content", av);
            if(this.content!=""){
            this._addText(this.content);
            }
        },

        _setTextSrcAttr: function(av) {

            this._set("textSrc", av);
            if(this.textSrc!=""){
                var articleText = xhr.get({
                    url: this.textSrc,
                    handleAs: "text"
                });
                var domNode = this;
                articleText.then( function(text){
                    domNode._addText(text);
                });
            }
        },

        _addText: function(text){
            var index = 0;

            while( this.measureNode.scrollHeight < this.height && index < text.length )
            {       
                this.containerNode.innerHTML += text.charAt(index);
                index++;
            }

            if(index < text.length){
                this.containerNode.innerHTML = text.substring(0,index-1);
            }
            else{
                this.ellipsisNode.innerHTML = "";
                this.endPointNode.innerHTML = "";
            }
        }   

    });
})
```

So essentially how this widget works is that if I call content and not `textSrc`, the string in content is sent to `addText()` to display it. Otherwise, xhr reads the URL of `textSrc` and sends the string in the URL to `addText()`. `addText()` adds a character from the string until the `measureNode` height surpasses the desired height (`containerNode` is in measureNode) or there are no characters left. There would be space at the end for an ellipsis and a "read more" anchor. Now the problem is that using content never works and here are some of the "symptoms"

1. The entire string is displayed even if there is overflow
2. The reason is that this.measureNode.scrollHeight is always 0. This is bizarre because it produces expected numbers when I use it with a URL of `textSrc`.

I fed just a string to both textSrc and content so something like `this._addText("blah blah blah blah ...")` in `_setContentAttr` and `domNode._addtext("etc")` in `textSrc` and the result was the same. Also I replaced instances of when I called this widget using `textSrc` with content and vice versa and again, only textSrc succeeds. This means that it's not a CSS problem. My guess is that it has something to do with deferred since xhr deferred the execution of the `textSrc` `addText` command while content did not. Can anyone explain to me what is going on and how I can solve this problem?

edit: So I think I isolated the problem to that the `offsetHeight`, `clientHeight` of a domNode in the widget are not active because maybe the html hasn't been rendered yet. Deferring the URL worked because by that time, the rendering was complete. However I still can't find a reasonable solution. The `postCreate` event doesn't work for some reason. Anyone know a workaround? Thanks!

Comment: you do know that CSS can do ellipsis for an overflow, without needing any Javascript? Or am I missing something about your needs that wouldn't work with the standard CSS option?

Comment: The CSS ellipsis overflow is only suitable for one-line divs. It will fail for multiline text so I created my own for my own needs. Besides I need a "read more" at the end of the text which CSS can't provide.

Comment: Fair enough; that makes sense. I thought I might have missed something obvious.  :)

Comment: Oh, by the way -- if you're doing an ellipsis, there is a dedicated character code for it, rather than three separate dots. HTML entity is `&hellip;` or unicode `2026`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I figured it out. So as I suspected `postCreate` and `_set(something)Attr` take place during the variable creation of your widget. The container for this widget used a `placeAt` command to put the widget in there. However `_addText(...)` was called before `placeAt` was called and so the widget was calculating `clientHeight` when it didn't even exist on the page yet. All I had to do was move the `_addText(...)` call after the widget's container `placeAt`  call and everything worked out fine.